# unable to install face_recognition library for python

Tags: python

I'm trying to install dbLib Library for executing python face_recognition as mentioned here

https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issuecomment-355899230

as I execute the command 
python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS

it says the following

```
C:\Python\dblib\dlib-master>python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS -
-yes DLIB_USE_CUDA
running install
running bdist_egg
running build
Detected Python architecture: 32bit
Detected platform: win32
Removing build directory C:\Python\dblib\dlib-master\./tools/python/build
Configuring cmake ...
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Failed to run MSBuild command:
    C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    Build started 1/9/2018 12:16:21 AM.
    Project "C:\Python\dblib\dlib-master\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.10.0\VC
TargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\Platf
ormToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8
.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK
version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and sele
cting "Retarget solution". [C:\Python\dblib\dlib-master\tools\python\build\CMake
Files\3.10.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "C:\Python\dblib\dlib-master\tools\python\build\CMakeF
iles\3.10.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
    Build FAILED.
    "C:\Python\dblib\dlib-master\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.10.0\VCTargetsP
ath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
    (Desktop_PlatformPrepareForBuild target) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\Pla
tformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version
 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SD
K version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and se
lecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Python\dblib\dlib-master\tools\python\build\CMa
keFiles\3.10.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)
    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.09
  Exit code: 1
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Python/dblib/dlib-master/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.
log".
error: cmake configuration failed!
```

please let me know what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install it with pip (through the pip install face_recognition command) after I had Boost and CMake installed.

to install face_recognition install Boost from here [here](http://www.boost.org/users/download/)
and then install Cmake if both get successful then you can directly install it.

and you also need to have visual studio C++ packages to ensure boost work properly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in py charm

face_recognition demands dlib.

dlib demands cmake.

But after you install the cmake its cannot be found, cause cmake is set as a environment variable.

So go at those steps:

1. Download and install CMAKE (https://cmake.org/download/)
2. Go to System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> New...
   Variable name: CMAKE
   Variable value: C:\Program Files\CMake\bin (Or where you installed the CMake bin directory)
3. Run CMD
4. pip install dlib (the processor will go full throttle on this)
5. pip install face_recognition

Answer (score 0):

this issue may occur due to incorrect versions of cmake and dlib

just type

pip install dlib==19.18
and
pip install cmake==3.18.4.post1

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have Visual Studio installed with C++ packages (C++11 library). Also state exactly the content of Output log file.

Answer (score -1):

I had a lot of trouble for downloading face_recognition in pycharm, but I finally figured it out.

I went to Terminal and typed:

```sh
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install cmake
sudo pip install dlib
sudo pip install face_recognition
```

Just make sure the latest version of pip is installed on your computer and you have CMae installed.

Also, if you are trying to use dlib and/or face_recognition in a pycharm project you can follow the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]